# NSDateFormatter results in null NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Any help is appreciated.

In the following code [ri EventDate] = '2014-02-07';

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *ed = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[ri EventDate]];
NSLog(@"eventDate: %@ -> %@", [ri EventDate], ed);
```

The outcome is: eventDate: 2014-02-07 -> (null)

BTW - Once I get this resolving to a string I will be changing the date format.  First things first...

Comment: I've never known dates to log in such a simple format. My bet is `[ri EventDate]` is already a string. Case Closed.

Comment: From the NSObject class - @property NSDate *EventDate;

Comment: NSObject for sure has no property EventDate

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `[ri EventDate]` is not nil?

Comment: The value is returned in the NSLog I showed in my original post.  The outcome is: eventDate: 2014-02-07 -> (null)

Comment: I think that @Joe is correct. It is strange that calling `stringFromDate:<some string>` does not throw an exception, but it actually just return `nil`.

Comment: @alockrem Even though you declared it as an `NSDate*` you can still accidentally assign an `NSString*` to it (usually with a warning unless using an id, or some form of reflection). Also I'm with Martin R, an exception would make more sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EventDate` has been accidentally assigned a string. You need to track down where this assignment occurred. If you have problems determining where it was assigned a string you can debug the property by declaring it as nonatomic, implementing the setter and then setting a conditional break point. Once the code breaks then you will have access to the stack trace that assigned the incorrect value. *Remember to remove the `nonantomic` if atomic is necessary, and remove the custom setter when done debugging*

Breakpoint Condition: `EventDate != nil && ![EventDate isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]`

[image: Debug]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am confident you are correct.  I will track this down and get it resolved.

Comment: Confirmation: The NSDate was stored as an NSString.  I didn't know that was possible.  After forcing it to be an NSDate it worked as expected.  Thank you again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

The code is right, the `[ri EventDate]` is probably a `NSString`, if you `NSLog()` a `NSDate`, the output is similar to `2013-10-09 19:27:30 +0000`, not 2014-02-02.

You must convert `[ri EventDate]` to `NSDate` first. Example:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:[ri EventDate]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am confident you are correct.  I will track this down and get it resolved.